# Show that function is bounded

Tags: limits, functions

Show that the function is bounded function
I think it is not (from the graph), but how to prove this?
the functions is $$\frac{1}{x^2 \sin x \ln x}$$

Comment: why should this be?

Comment: @kur Bounded ... **where** ? you must specificy some domain as that functions has lots of poles or points on the real line where it isn't defined "naturally" .

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ but what i mean is that this function is not bounded because of the fact what is happening with the graph close to the point "0"

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If it is considered on $(0,\infty)$, then $\sin x$ has zeroes (witx $x\ln x\neq0$), hence the function is unbounded.

Comment: How about $g(x) = \sin 2x / \sin x$? The denominator, $\sin x$, has infinitely many zeroes, but $g$ is bounded. In the original problem the numerator is always non-zero, but your hint isn't always true.

Comment: @LeonAragones It is a hint. I hope that OP can observe that the numerator is 1. :-)

Comment: nominator, i think numerator...

Comment: @kurkowski Certainly, numerator. Lapsus calami. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: calculate the limit of your function, $f(x) = 1 / (x^2 \sin x \ln x)$, in $x = \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true because $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow k\pi} x^2 \sin(x) \ln(x) = 0$, for $k \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to exploit the facts that in a right neighbourhood of zero we have 
$$\frac{2}{\pi}x\leq\sin x\leq x $$
and:
$$ -\frac{1}{e}\leq x\log(x)\leq 0.$$

Comment: Do we have serial downvoters in action?